# Grouping objects in HTML for Javascript Manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have not written the code yet, but wanted to know general direction. My entire front end consists of HTML tables. It actually has an excel look. 
I was thinking of generating default pages and then using JS to shift entire rows and columns based on ids. 
The table cells might contain - Label, Textboxes, Images, Checkboxes etc.

In what way should I address the row or with Javascript assemble a group of elements within the ,  tags. Do not want a solution with `<div>`

So if I write a `<th>` as

```
<th class="col1" colspan="1"><%= nodes.last == @map.keys.first ? label_tag("#{nodes.last.to_label}") : label_tag("#{nodes.last}") %></th>
```

I could give it an id, but then would selecting that elementbyId in JS cause for even the context of the row to be picked up

Comment: For tables, within HTML there is colgroup and row, in DOM there are the same but also class or really any attribute value for grouping with the query selector API.

Comment: Have you looked into JQuery yet? You can select by class, which seems to be exactly what you want. You can select all class items and modify them by using `$(".classname"). https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can give every row an attribute contain Id number, then you can read this numbers in JQuery and Re-Sort your table.